# All figures are showing up as a solid black rectangle

Tags: graphics

I am working on a TeX project. I can compile everything without error nor warnings. However, all of my figures are showing up as a solid black rectangle.
Does anyone have a clue of what might be going on?

I have all the figures with the correct filenames at the project folder.

Minimal working code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{fig3.png}
    \caption{Something goes here}\label{fig3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Do you happen to pass `draft` as an option to your documentclass or one of the packages?

Comment: please put your code in question. link can after some time vanish and other will no able to see your problem. see if you maybe load `graphicx` package with option `demo`. remove this option, if exist. if is this question related to your previous, than replace `\documentclass[review,demo]{elsarticle}` with `\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by comments (iop use `demo` option  at loading `\documentclass`).